# How to programmatically run a gradle build task from a Restful methode or java class

Tags: java, gradle

*Please, did somebody know how to programmatically run a gradle build task from a Restful methode or java class?
Thank you.*

Answer (score 8):

It's not really clear from your question what you want to achieve, but it seems to me that you are looking for something like the [Gradle Tooling API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/embedding.html). It allows to:

> - Query the details of a build, including the project hierarchy and the project dependencies, external dependencies (including source and
>     Javadoc jars), source directories and tasks of each project.
> - Execute a build and listen to stdout and stderr logging and progress messages (e.g. the messages shown in the 'status bar' when
>     you run on the command line).
> - Execute a specific test class or test method.
> - Receive interesting events as a build executes, such as project configuration, task execution or test execution.
> - Cancel a build that is running.
> - Combine multiple separate Gradle builds into a single composite build.
> - The Tooling API can download and install the appropriate Gradle version, similar to the wrapper.
> - The implementation is lightweight, with only a small number of dependencies. It is also a well-behaved library, and makes no
>     assumptions about your classloader structure or logging configuration.
> - This makes the API easy to embed in your application.

There are some examples you can find within `samples/toolingApi` directory of Gradle distribution.

As for your task, it seems, that you have to create an instance of `GradleConnector` via it's `forProjectDirectory(File projectDir)` method, then get it's `ProjectConnection`(via `connect()`) and `BuildLauncher`(via `newBuild()`). And finally with the instance of the `BuildLauncher` you can run any task you need. Here is one example from it's [javadocs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/tooling/BuildLauncher.html):

```
try {
    BuildLauncher build = connection.newBuild();

    //select tasks to run:
    build.forTasks("clean", "test");

    //include some build arguments:
    build.withArguments("--no-search-upward", "-i", "--project-dir", "someProjectDir");

    //configure the standard input:
    build.setStandardInput(new ByteArrayInputStream("consume this!".getBytes()));

    //in case you want the build to use java different than default:
    build.setJavaHome(new File("/path/to/java"));

    //if your build needs crazy amounts of memory:
    build.setJvmArguments("-Xmx2048m", "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m");

    //if you want to listen to the progress events:
    ProgressListener listener = null; // use your implementation
    build.addProgressListener(listener);

    //kick the build off:
    build.run();
 } finally {
    connection.close();
 }
```